# If nil is treated as a logical false in Clojure, why does (false? nil) return false

Tags: clojure

The book **Living Clojure** explains that the type `nil` is treated the same as logical false.

So I expected `(false? nil)` to return `true`, which it doesn't. `(true? nil)` also doesn't. Both return `false`, which makes me think that Clojure treats `nil` neither as `true` nor `false`.

On the other hand, `(not nil)` evaluates to `true`. So I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction is testing for *logical truth*, versus the *values* themselves.

The values `nil` and `false` are treated as *logically false* in Clojure. All other values are treated as *logically true*.

The predicates `false?` and `true?` test explicitly for the *values* `false` and `true` respectively, as you have noted. These predicates are not often used in Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation of false?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/false_q):

> Returns true if x is the value false, false otherwise.

So the function checks if the parameter equals the value `false` instead of checking if it is [logically false](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/flow#_truth).

In Clojure, all values are either logically true or logically false, so they can be used in conditional expressions. The only logically false values are `nil` and `false`.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers already.

People sometimes use the terms **falsey** (`nil` and `false`) and **truthy** (all other values) to describe Clojure values.
It is sometimes handy to coerce values into Boolean `true` or `false`.  I even wrote [a handy function](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#the-truth-is-not-ambiguous) for this:

```
(defn truthy?
  "Returns true if arg is logical true (neither nil nor false); otherwise returns false."
  [arg]
  (if arg true false))

(defn falsey?
  "Returns true if arg is logical false (either nil or false); otherwise returns false. Equivalent
   to (not (truthy? arg))."
  [arg]
  (if arg false true))
```

These are sometimes convenient when filtering values or constructing a vector of **true/false** values.
Later, I discovered Clojure already had a function `boolean` which does the same thing as `truthy?`.

Be sure to see [this list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially the Clojure CheatSheet. Enjoy!

Comment: Unless for some DSL i'd just use `boolean` and `not` instead of inventing something more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

> The book **Living Clojure** explains that the type `nil` is treated
> the same as logical `false`.

First, `nil` is a value - not a type.

- Its type is nameless.
- Any reference (object) type can have it as a value.

Second, `nil` and `false` are distinct values. You can easily write code that treats them differently:

```
(map #(case %, nil 1, false 2) [nil false])
=> (1 2)
```

And `nil`, for example, puns to an empty sequence,

```
(count nil)
=> 0
```

whereas `false` does not

```
(count false)
Execution error ...
```

**It is as the first argument to `if` that `nil` is equivalent to `false`**.

Paraphrasing [the official document](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#if):

> ```
> (if test then else?)
> ```
>
> ... evaluates `test`, then ...
>
> - if it is `nil` or `false`, evaluates and yields `else`;
> - otherwise evaluates and yields `then`.
>
> If `else` is not supplied, it defaults to `nil`.
>
> All of the other conditionals (`when`, `if-let`, `cond`,
> ...) follow the same logic:
>
> - `nil` and `false` constitute logical falsity;
> - everything else constitutes logical truth.

As for the predicate function `false?`, it might have been defined ...

```
(defn false? [x]
  (case x, false true, false))
```

... which, for any argument but the exact value `false`, returns `false`.

By the way, the Clojure values `false` and `true` are the Java objects `Boolean/FALSE` and `Boolean/TRUE`:

```
Boolean/FALSE
=> false
(if Boolean/FALSE 1 2)
=> 2
(type false)
=> java.lang.Boolean
```